# Adding select>option as list items using JS

Tags: javascript

I have a button that says 'Add topping' and when it's pressed, there has to be appeared a new select tag that contains certain value tags. I almost did it but when I press the button, the  tag appears and immediately disappears. What's wrong?

HTML:

```
      <div class="form-group" id='add_one'>
        <br>
        <h5>You can add up to 3 toppings to your pizza!</h5>
        <ol id="list"></ol>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add topping</button>
      </div>
```

JS:

```
var toppings = ['Zucchini', 'Fresh Garlic', 'Black Olives', 'Anchovies',
  'Barbecue Chicken', 'Artichoke', 'Spinach', 'Ham', 'Sausage', 'Mushrooms'];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#add').onclick = () => {

    const topping = document.createElement('select', {
      'name': 'Topping',
      'class': 'form-control'
    });
    list.appendChild(topping);
    toppings.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
      const ch_topping = document.createElement('option');
      ch_topping.innerHTML += item;
      topping.appendChild(ch_topping);
    });
  };
});
```

```js
var toppings = ['Zucchini', 'Fresh Garlic', 'Black Olives', 'Anchovies',
  'Barbecue Chicken', 'Artichoke', 'Spinach', 'Ham', 'Sausage', 'Mushrooms'];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#add').onclick = () => {

    const topping = document.createElement('select', {
      'name': 'Topping',
      'class': 'form-control'
    });
    list.appendChild(topping);
    toppings.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
      const ch_topping = document.createElement('option');
      ch_topping.innerHTML += item;
      topping.appendChild(ch_topping);
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id='add_one'>
        <br>
        <h5>You can add up to 3 toppings to your pizza!</h5>
        <ol id="list"></ol>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add topping</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @brk mentioned,

Removing `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {/* ... */}`
would solve your problem. **And you don't need to modify any HTML code.**

> But I'd suggest to use `document.getElementById` as
>   `document.querySelector()` is more generic and may perform worse as 
>   compared to `document.getElementById`
>
> Check the performance diff b/w them [here](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector)

---

*And I have made some changes to you code as it is appending more than 3 dropdowns, feel free to change it*

```js
var toppings = ['Zucchini', 'Fresh Garlic', 'Black Olives', 'Anchovies',
  'Barbecue Chicken', 'Artichoke', 'Spinach', 'Ham', 'Sausage', 'Mushrooms'
];
var appended = 0;
var maxAppended = 3;

document.getElementById('add').onclick = () => {
  appended+=1;
  if(appended <= maxAppended){
  const topping = document.createElement('select', {
    'name': 'Topping',
    'class': 'form-control'
  });
  list.appendChild(topping);
  toppings.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    const ch_topping = document.createElement('option');
    ch_topping.innerHTML += item;
    topping.appendChild(ch_topping);
  });
  }
  else {
  /* Your logic goes here*/
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id='add_one'>
  <h5>You can add up to 3 toppings to your pizza!</h5>
  <ol id="list">
  </ol>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add topping</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it returns TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

Comment: It seems working in the above snippet. Can you your code?

Answer (score 0):

button default type is `submit` change it to `button type='button'`.

Also you may not need `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',` if the scripts are loaded after dom is ready

```js
var toppings = ['Zucchini', 'Fresh Garlic', 'Black Olives', 'Anchovies',
  'Barbecue Chicken', 'Artichoke', 'Spinach', 'Ham', 'Sausage', 'Mushrooms'
];


document.querySelector('#add').onclick = () => {

  const topping = document.createElement('select', {
    'name': 'Topping',
    'class': 'form-control'
  });
  list.appendChild(topping);
  toppings.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    const ch_topping = document.createElement('option');
    ch_topping.innerHTML += item;
    topping.appendChild(ch_topping);
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id='add_one'>
  <br>
  <h5>You can add up to 3 toppings to your pizza!</h5>
  <ol id="list"></ol>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add topping</button>
</div>
```

Comment: did that but now I'm having trouble with this TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null